# JQuery get id from $(this) not working, but getting another attribute does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched the web and tried every proposed method I can find, but nothing seems right for my case.

The problem is this:
I need to get the id of the checked element so I know which element to change/manipulate later.
My problem is most curious because I do a `$(this).attr("tag");` and get the right value returned for later use.
But then I try `$(this).attr("id");` and when I alert it, it's just an empty alert. 
I have also tried alternate methods.

I've done `this.id` and `var $this = $(this); $this.id/$this.attr("id");`

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it works on one attribute, but not another when they're both within the same method, right after one another.

```
 $('.jq-toggleExternal').click(function () {
                var refNo = $(this).attr("tag");
                var checked = $(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked');
                var controls = getReferenceContolsByRefNo(refNo);
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                alert(id);

 <asp:CheckBox ID="r_chkRef1External" runat="server" CssClass="jq-toggleExternal"
                        tag="1" Text="Ekstern" onClick="changed(this)" />
```

I've also tried changing the ID to id, but same result and if I change the attr search to attr("ID") it says undefined.

Any possible solutions/alternative ways to get the id is highly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the *generated* HTML code. Does the element have an ID?

Comment: The problem seems to be, as usual, IE. Because your example works for me in firefox, but not in IE, which is the main browser for the project I'm working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the id of the element that triggered the 'click' event this should work:

```
$('.jq-toggleExternal').click(function (e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
});
```

I suppose that in your code you are closing the function bracket (}), I don't find it in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed $(this).prop('id'); ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="r_chkRef1External" runat="server" CssClass="jq-toggleExternal"
                        tag="1" Text="Ekstern" onClick="changed(this)" clientID="abc" />
```

i think in ASP.net **clientid** use then in jquery it shows  as id

```
instead of using the hardcoded version use the ClientID property of the control like for example:

<%= btnSomeId.ClientID %>
```